# Signup and login using Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, devise

I have fully functional web app. I am developing rails API for it. 
I am using devise for authentication in my rails app. 
I want to  create mobile app for my web app. I want to implement login and signup in my rails app so that user can only see data belongs to them.
I am little bit confused here.

How can i implement them ?

i found gems like 
simple_token_authentication
devis_authenticable etc.

but i can't figure out how to use them
I also know about token authentication but how can i implement signup and login from mobile app.

Please explain me via basic example.
I have made a sample app to try this in it i have

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

and
   **User model generated by devise gem**

Also I have different module API and separate product_controller inside it.

thanks in advance

Comment: `user` is missing a semicolon `:user`

Comment: So you want login/signup functionality right?

Comment: @Cyzanfar yes exactly but via api

Comment: Which Api? do you want to make your own authentication system or use the Devise one?

Comment: @Cyzanfar i want to use Devise

Comment: What confuses you in the devise documentation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76085/discussion-between-adt-and-cyzanfar).

Comment: I want to signup and login via api not webapp

Answer (score 0):

Set up devise to work with JSON and use AJAX in your mobile app to login/signup.
Look here for example: http://blog.andrewray.me/how-to-set-up-devise-ajax-authentication-with-rails-4-0/